# Dont understand how slideshow loops without FOR or WHILE loop being set?

Tags: javascript, html

I am sure the answer for this is very simple and somewhat obvious but I am slightly confused on how the below code is looping through.  As you can see it is for a simple slide show and what I cannot seem to understand is how the slide show loops round without a FOR or WHILE loop.  I can see that the function is called by SetTimeout but my understanding is that method only calls the function once?

```
<img name="slide" width="400" height="200" />

var i = 0;          // Start Point
var images = [];    // Images Array
var time = 3000;    // Time Between Switch

// Image List
images[0] = "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/animals";
images[1] = "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports";
images[2] = "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/food";
images[3] = "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/people";

// Change Image
function changeImg(){
document.slide.src = images[i];

// Check If Index Is Under Max
if(i < images.length - 1){
  // Add 1 to Index
  i++; 
} else { 
    // Reset Back To O
    i = 0;
}

// Run function every x seconds
setTimeout("changeImg()", time);
}

// Run function when page loads  
window.onload=changeImg;
```

Comment: At the end of the function, `setTimeout()` schedules a new call, and the function runs again after `time` has passed. Although a more current way to achieve that would be `setInterval()`

Comment: setTimeout does call the function once, but at the end of the function it calls it again

Comment: Thanks for clearing that one up!  Slightly confusing as on w3schools it advises that setTimeout() only executes once and if you need a repeat execution then to use setInterval(),  seems they both do the same thing.

Comment: No, they do not do the same thing.  As explained before, the last thing `changeImg()` does is executes a setTimeout, which recursively calls the same method, so it's an indirect loop.

Comment: I understand, so setTimeout() calls the function, the function runs and at the end of the function it is called again by setTimeout().  Bingo!  There's the loop!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You attach the method to the window load event handler
2. The browser fires the load event on the window, and the changeImg function executes
3. changeImg runs, and at the end executes a setTimeout for the changeImg function after "time" duration
4. The "time" passes and setTimeout kicks off changeImg
5. changeImg runs, and at the end executes a setTimeout for the changeImg function after "time" duration
6. The "time" passes and setTimeout kicks off changeImg
7. change Img runs, ...

As such, through the recursion you are creating an indirect loop of the logic.